# Android Trouble with displaying GPS Status on the Button

Tags: android, gps

In my application,if GPS is off and application is launched, a alert dialog will appear having buttons "GPS Settings" and "cancel" and if GPS is on and application will launched nothing happens. In the application, there is a button that displays the GPS status i.e if GPS is on, it will display "GPS is on" and if off "GPS is off, turn it on" and when user clicks it, it will open GPS Settings and when user enables GPS and returns back, the button must display "GPS is on". I am finding trouble in displaying the status on the button when user enables the GPS. Please help. I am new to android.

```
      private Button GPSState;
        GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        LocationManager locationManager;

                locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                    // no GPS provider is enabled
                    // displaying GPS status on the button and and opening GPS Settings
                    GPSState.setText("GPS is OFF.Turn it On");
                    GPSState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                        }
                    });
        // creating alertdialog
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                    builder.setTitle("Settings");
                    builder.setMessage("Enable GPS for the Application");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("GPS Setting",

                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                            .setTitle("How to use Application")
                                            .setMessage(
                                                    "You must enable the GPS in order to use this application. Press Activate and then press Power Button twice in order to send the alert message to the selected contacts")
                                            .setNeutralButton(
                                                    "OK",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(
                                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int which) {
                                                            // do something // for
                                                            // returning back to //
                                                            // application
                                                            dialog.cancel();

                                                        }
                                                    }).show();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });

                    builder.show();

                } else { // GPS provider is enabled }
                    GPSState.setText("GPS is On");

                }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

GPSState.setText("GPS is on");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `startActivityForResult` instead `startActivity` when you call Settings to enable GPS. After user enable/disable GPS in Settings page, he/she will press *back* button to back to your app. In this moment, method `onActivityResult` is called. You can set your text in here.

How to set your text? Roughly :

```
onActivityResult() {
    GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
    LocationManager locationManager;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!isGPSEnabled) GPSState.setText("GPS is off");
    else GPSState.setText("GPS is on");
}
```

Currently I am not seeing android documentation or eclipse. But I think this can give you a clue. I know the method is not like that, though.

Comment: i am done with startActivityForResult, please tell me how will i set text onActivityResult.

Comment: thanks a lot. it helped. actually i get confused in onActivityResult. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
 public static boolean isGpS(Context mContext)
    {
         final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
    }
```

In your onCreate write this :

```
if(!Utils.isGpS(Youractivity.this)
{   
   buildAlertMessageNoGps();
}
```

This is the method for showAlertDialog :

```
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps()
 {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Yout GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                       startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

**NOTE :** Don't forget to apply permission in AndroidMenifest file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```